# How can I pull a value from one column based on the values of another column?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

[image]

When the value in the "Amount Owed" column becomes less than `0`, I want the value in the "Year" column to appear under "Year Paid Off."

For example, if the "Amount Owed" dropped below zero at "Year" `1`, I would want `1` to appear under "Year Paid Off"

I've tried a few different ways but nothing seems to work. I thought I could just do something like `=if(f6:f130<0,c6:c130)` but that seems way off.

Answer (score 0):

if there will be **only one** possible negative value try this:

**E2:** `=FILTER(C6:C130;F6:F130 <0)`

if there will be **more than one** possible negative values try this:

**E2:** `=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(C6:C130;F6:F130 <0))`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much that works great! I went with the second option because there are multiple negatives, which outputted all along row 2. To get rid of the superfluous values I found that you can simply use E2: = index(filter(c6:c130,f6:f130<0),1) to only draw the first value.